# When i am opening xpage in web browser it display error msg page cannot be displayed

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

my lotus server name is "TESTSAN/SAN" when i am opening xpage in web the address

is like "http://testsan/san/testxpages.nsf/test.xsp" , and display an error page cannot be displayed.

but i am removing org name from web address it is working. pls tell me wt is the problem.

thank u.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TESTSAN/SAN is the hierarchical Domino name for the server. The server also has a fully qualified domain name (FQDN).

For web applications you need to use the FQDN (or another domain name that points to the server and that can be resolved using DNS). You can not use the hierarchical name as this cannot be resolved by your browser.